# adding translations to database records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am at the end off my project. I implemented few languages.
But this moment, I have categories that are placed in database, but these categories are in my native Latvian language, what would be the trick to be able change language of these records simultaneously with display language change.

It means that If I choose locale en, then these category names are displayed in english.
Some ideas!
To store ultiple language translation within the records, I think it's bad idea.
Or to store just put latvian category name as id inside `<%= I18n.t 'category_id_in_latvian'%>`
and just in yml files put the translation ?
Or there are other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the Globalize Gem:

[Github of globalize3 Gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3)

This gem should do exactly what you need. ;)

And if it doesn't, please, explain why by  providing more details on what you want to do and I'll update my answer according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, but I have about 200 categories that has to be translated into 3 diferent languages, using console to add the translation can taka a while. So to make it faster, I have to add that code into seed file and then run rake db:seed ? Or there are faster way to do it ? Thanks

Comment: Hi! Well... yep I don't really know a good way to add translations as quick as you want. For your categories, the best way would be the seed file as you describe it. If you use an admin part like active_admin, it exists some gems that should interest you: https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize3 . But still, it wouldn't be as fast as a rake task, but it would be better than  doing it by hand in the console.